# Removing leading zeros of a numpy array without using a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, numpy

How can I remove only the leading zeroes from a numpy array without using for a loop?

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0])

# Desired output
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```

I have written the following code

```
x[min(min(np.where(x>=1))):]
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient solution.

Comment: `np.trim_zeros(x, 'f')` - [internally this is a `for` loop](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L2230-L2278), but in many cases, this probably will be the most efficient way.

Comment: What are typical values for the length of `x` and the number of leading zeros?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `np.trim_zeros(x, 'f')`.

The 'f' means to trim the zeros from the front. 
Option 'b' would trim the zeros from the back.
Default option 'fb' trims them from both sides.

```
x = np.array([0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0])
# [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0]
np.trim_zeros(x, 'f')
# [1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0]
```

Comment: As said in other answers or comments, [the trim_zero() implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L2230-L2278) seems to use for loops internally, so should we find alternative solutions? Or otherwise, if the OP was just looking for a library function to avoid to manually write loops, then this answer would be good enough, but the question should be made more clear.

Answer (score 4):

Since `np.trim_zeros` [uses a `for` loop](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L2230-L2278), here's a truly vectorized solution:

```
x = x[np.where(x != 0)[0][0]:]
```

However I'm not sure at which point it starts to be more efficient than `np.trim_zeros`. It will be more efficient in the worst case (i.e. array with most of leading zeros).

Anyway, it can be a useful learning example.

Double-sided trim:

```
>>> idx = np.where(x != 0)[0]
>>> x = x[idx[0]:1+idx[-1]]
```

Comment: Your answer has intrigued me, so I've done a little research. Isn't slicing internally also treated as a for loop? Referring to: [this post](https://www.quora.com/How-is-slicing-implemented-in-python).

Comment: That article is about `list`. Are you sure numpy does the same? Slicing it's just a call to the `__getitem__` method with a `slice` object, e.g. `x[2:4]` is the same as `x.__getitem__(slice(2,4))`. It depends on how numpy implements that method.

Comment: I am not sure, hence the question. I was curious about the `for`-less implementation and wanted to see it. I am, however, unable to retrace the steps in the post for `numpy.ndarray` object. I've also tried to snoop in the numpy sources, but to no avail. Anyway, I guess we should not be discussing it here.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a numpy approach that short-circuits. It utilizes the fact that the representation of `0` for any (?) dtype are zero-bytes.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

# check assumption that for example 0.0f is represented as 00 00 00 00
allowed_dtypes = set()
for dt in map(np.dtype, itertools.chain.from_iterable(np.sctypes.values())):
    try:
        if not np.any(np.zeros((1,), dtype=dt).view(bool)):
            allowed_dtypes.add(dt)
    except:
        pass

def trim_fast(a):
    assert a.dtype in allowed_dtypes
    cut = a.view(bool).argmax() // a.dtype.itemsize
    if a[cut] == 0:
        return a[:0]
    else:
        return a[cut:]
```

Comparison with other methods:

[image]

Code to generate plot:

```
def np_where(a):
    return a[np.where(a != 0)[0][0]:]

def np_trim_zeros(a):
    return np.trim_zeros(a, 'f')

import perfplot

tf, nt, nw = trim_fast, np_trim_zeros, np_where
def trim_fast(A): return [tf(a) for a in A]
def np_trim_zeros(A): return [nt(a) for a in A]
def np_where(A): return [nw(a) for a in A]

perfplot.save('tz.png',
    setup=lambda n: np.clip(np.random.uniform(-n, 1, (100, 20*n)), 0, None),
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(2, 11)],
    kernels=[
        trim_fast,
        np_where,
        np_trim_zeros
        ],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    xlabel='zeros per nonzero',
    equality_check=None
    )
```